# Joi for Hapi doesn't translate one element of array as array

Tags: node.js, swagger, hapi.js, joi

I'm trying to use array value for the url. So I have this as Joi validation.

```
entity: Joi.array().allow(['person','location','organization']).unique().single().default(['person'])
```

It works fine if I do this

```
http://something.com/query?entity=person&person=organization
```

It sees `entity` as an array so when I print out value from `request`

```
console.log(request.query.entity) // ['person', 'organization']
```

However, if I do this

```
http://something.com/query?entity=person
```

I get `entity` as string instead of `['person']`

```
console.log(request.query.entity) // 'person'
```

What I want is I want this url `http://something.com/query?entity=person` for `entity` to be seen as `['person']`

Comment: http://something.com/query?entity=['person']

Answer (score 4):

`.allow()` lists the valid values for the `entity` array, but you want to specify the type of the items in the array:

```
entity: Joi.array().unique().single().items(Joi.string().valid(['person','location','organization'])).default(['person'])
```

From the repl:

```
> schema = Joi.object({ entity: Joi.array().unique().single().items(Joi.string().valid(['person','location','organization'])).default(['person'])});
> Joi.validate({entity: 'person' }, schema)
{ error: null, value: { entity: [ 'person' ] } }
```